# Search value by ajax call using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to fetch data by ajax call using Rails 3.I have a form which is given below.

## views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user ,:url => {:action => "search" } do |f| %>
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :user_no,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"user number" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

This form says when user will type user_no and as soon as number will typed the search action will execute.A table should present below of this form to show other data by matching according to that user_no.That table is given below.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>User Email</th>
<th>User Number</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This table will be hide initially.Once search will complete it will be display with appropriate data.

The below is my controller page.

## controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @user=User.new
 end 
 def search

 end
end
```

All the data(i.e-user no,name and email) already saved in DB.Please help me to complete this task using Rails Ajax and Data should display without reloading the page after form submit.I am using Rails version 3.2.19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then try something like that:

**In controller:**

```
def search
  @user = User.find_by_user_no(params[:user_no])
end
```

**In view with form:**

```
<%= form_for :user ,:url => {:action => "search" }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
       <%= f.text_field :user_no,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"user number" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

`remote: true` means that request will be asynchronous.

**In view with table:**

```
<div id="search-output-table">
   <%= render partial: "search_output_table", locales: {user: @user} %>
</div>
```

**In `app/views/users/_search.js.erb`:**

```
$("#search-output-table").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(partial: "search_output_table") ) %>");
```

**In `app/views/users/_search_output_table.html.erb`:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Email</th>
    <th>User Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.number %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi,Gena Ok,But action should execute after typing the number in text filed because there is no submit button.

Comment: Yes, i see. In this case you should just setup [onInput](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event for input form with javascript.

Comment: Hi Gena , by applying this logic i was trying one app but facing some issue can you please help me..?If yes then I will post the link.

Comment: Gena,Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695568/database-values-are-not-coming-in-same-page-without-reloading-in-rails-3.Please help me.