# Database values are not coming in same page without reloading in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want after searching by receipt number the values should display in same page without reloading the page using Rails3. But I am getting all values but not in the same page. I am providing my code below.

**views/homes/home.html.erb**

```
<% if current_admin %>  
<div id="page-container" class="full-width">
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
<ul class="navbar-nav-custom pull-left">
<li class="visible-md visible-lg">    
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle-side-content">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="width:100%; line-height:19px;">
SWARGADWAR, PURI MUNICIPALITY<br>
<span class="fontssizediv2">Government of Odisha</span>
</a>
<div id="loading" class="display-none"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
</div>
<div id="header-nav-section" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 clearfix">
<ul class="navbar-nav-custom pull-left visible-xs visible-sm" id="mobile-nav">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</header><aside id="page-sidebar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
<div class="side-scrollable">
<div class="mini-profile">
<div class="mini-profile-options">
<a href="/sessions/logout_admin" class="badge badge-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Log out">
<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img src="/assets/personsphoto.png" alt="abhijeetca" class="img-circle" height="120" style="height:120px;">
</a>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-tabs-con">
<div class="tab-content" style="padding-top:0px;">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="side-tab-menu">
<nav id="primary-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="/homes/home" class="active"><i class="gi gi-display"></i>Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/reports/view_report"><i class="gi gi-table"></i>Report</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</aside><div id="pre-page-content">
<h1><i class="themed-color"><img src="/assets/odishalogo.png" border="0" name="odishalogo" style="height:80px;"></i><div class="tpaddingdiv2">(E-RECEIPT)</div></h1>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="page-content">
<ul class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-top">
<li>
<a href="index.html"><i class="gi gi-display"></i></a>
</li>
<li>Harischandra Sahayata Yojana Slip</li>
</ul>
<div class="tbpaddingdiv2">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="float:none; margin:auto;">
    <%= form_for :sdf ,:url => {:action => "scan_report" },remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
        <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Receipt No. scan",:onchange => 'this.form.submit();' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="block block-themed" id="hcsy_block" style="display:none;" >

</div>
</div>
<footer>
<div class="pull-right">
Maintained <i class="fa fa-pencil text-danger"></i> by <strong><a href="http://www.oditeksolutions.com" target="_blank">Oditek Solutions</a></strong>
</div>
<div class="pull-left">
<span id="year-copy"></span> &copy; <strong><a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality</a></strong>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
<a href="#" id="to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
<% end %>
```

**controller/homes_controller.rb:**

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @sdf=TSdf.new
    end
    def scan_report
        @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
        if @sdf && @sdf.HCSY_Status=='YES'
             @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)
             respond_to do |format|
                format.html
                format.js 
             end
        else
            flash[:alert]="Scan number is invalid"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            redirect_to :action => "home"
        end


    end
end
```

**scan_report.js.erb**

```
$("#hcsy_block").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(partial: "hcsy_output_table",locals: "{hcsy: @hcsy }" ) ) %>");
$("#hcsy_block").slideDown(350);
```

**hcsy_output_table.html.erb**

```
<div class="block-title">
        <div class="block-options">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option enable-tooltip" data-toggle="block-collapse" title="Toggle block's content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
        </div>
            <h4>Harischandra Sahayata Yojana Form</h4>
    </div>
    <!--1st_total_div-->
    <div class="block-content">
      <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
      <div class="block-title"><h5>Personal Details</h5></div>
            <div class="block-content full">
                    <div class="totalaligndiv">
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Receipt No :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Receipt_No %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date &amp; Time :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Created_On %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Name of Deceased :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Deceased_Name %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Mobile No :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Mobile_No %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Beneficiary Name :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Name %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Occupation :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Occupation %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Relation with Deceased :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Rel_With_Decease %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address Line - I :</div></span>
                        <textarea name="versions comments"  class="form-control" rows="3"><%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Address1 %></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address Line - II :</div></span>
                        <textarea name="versions comments"  class="form-control" rows="3"><%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Address2 %></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Village/City :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Village %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Block :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Block %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">District :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Dist %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">State :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_State %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Country :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_Country %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Police Station :</div></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Beneficiary_PS %>" > 
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totalaligndiv">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
            <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
                <div class="block-title"><h5>Annual Income From Sources</h5></div>
                    <div class="block-content full">
                        <div class="totalaligndiv">
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">BPL :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.BPL %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Govt. Services :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Govt_Service %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Business :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Business %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Land Property :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Land_Property %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Others :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Others %>" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left" style="height:55px;">
                          &nbsp; 
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right:0px;">
              <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
                    <div class="block-title"><h5>Application Details</h5></div>
                    <div class="block-content full">
                        <div class="totalaligndiv">
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Purpose :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Brahmin %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Amount Required :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Amout_Required %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div>Has he/she received any assistance earlier from this fund</div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left">
                          <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Status :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Received_Fund_Earlier %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Prev. Receipt No. :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Prev_Receipt_No %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Amount Received :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Prev_Amount_Received %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date of Received :</div></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= hcsy.Prev_Date_Received %>" > 
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tpaddingdiv1">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="<%= hcsy.D_Photo %>" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 text-center bpaddingdiv1">Deceased Photo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="<%= hcsy.B_Photo %>" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 bpaddingdiv1 text-center">Donor Photo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center bpaddingdiv1"><img src="/assets/signaturetwo.jpg" border="0" name="signature" height="140" class="borderblackdiv"></div>
                <div class="fontweightbolddiv fontssizediv3 bpaddingdiv1 text-center">Donor Thumb</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**scan_report.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "hcsy_output_table", locals: {hcsy: @hcsy} %>
```

I need `_hcsy_output_table.html.erb` should render in same home page just after form and it should come without reloading the page means when user will put the receipt number the form will submit and suddenly all value will display.

Comment: Can you please try to narrow your problem down? As it is right now it is pretty unclear what exactly your problem is and where it is.

Comment: Hi mhlz,I want first user will put the receipt number inside the form(i.e-home.html.erb) once scan_report action execution will finish according to receipt no the data will fetch from DB and it will display in that same home.html.erb page.Where i am getting problem Once scan_report execution finishies all data is coming in another page under this url(i.e-http://localhost:3000/homes/scan_report) ._hcsy_output_table.html.erb should append in home.html.erb file.This process should execute withput reload the page.

Comment: Shortly..Think about one barcode scan report.Once bar-code value is detecting all the data regarding that code is displaying in same page.My app is just like this.